# Is there a facility to unzip files using .net 4.0 framework

Tags: .net, zip

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I want to unzip a file using .net 4.0. Is there a facility to unzip files using .net 4.0 framework? Is there any possibility to use ZipArchive with 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/). I've used this on previous projects and it's an excellent library for reading zip files.

Comment: Thank you very much I will have try on it.